# Capturing key event for backspace

Tags: javascript, jquery, android

I am having difficulty capturing the backspace key as a keyboard Event in javascript/jQuery. In Firefox, Safari, Opera, Chrome, and on the iPhone/iPad, I capture a keyup event on a text input box like this:

```
$(id_input).keyup(function(event) {
   that.GetHints($(this).val().trim(), event, fieldName);
});
```

This event captures user keystrokes, then sends them to a function to issue an ajax lookup call.

My problem comes when a user wishes to backspace over a character he/she already typed. In all the browsers to which I have access except for my Droid phone, when I press the backspace key, this keyup event captures the value returned by $(this).val().trim() and sends it on to process in function GetHints. On the Droid, however, neither this keyup nor an equivalent keydown event fires until the user backspaces over every character in $(this).

So, for example, if I type "cu" then backspace over the "u" leaving only "c" in the input field, in all browsers except Droid, the keyup event will fire and call function `GetHints("c", event, fieldName)`. On the Droid, the keyup event never fires.

What am I missing? How/why does this backspace key, on either the soft keyboard or the hard keyboard, on my Droid not function as expected? How do I work around this?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, because it sounds like an android issue:  have you tried the keydown or keypress events?  Maybe you'll have more luck with those.

Comment: yea, i would try the keypress instead of the keyup

Answer (score 2):

You could poll for changes in the text (using `setInterval`). This would probably be more reliable. For example, keyup wouldn't fire if the user does right-click -> cut. Polling alone would be less responsive, but you could combine it with keyup to keep it snappy. Polling would be a bit more processor heavy.

Try something along these lines:

```
var oldText = '';
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    var text = $(id_input).val().trim();
    if(text != oldText){
        oldText = text;
        that.GetHints(text, fieldName);
    }
}, 500);
```

Tweak the interval duration as necessary.

I'm not sure what `that.GetHints` does with `event`, but obviously, you wouldn't be able to pass that in using the polling approach (because there isn't an actual event being fired). Is this a problem?

You can use `clearInterval(timer);` to stop polling if you want to.

You could keep your existing keyup function as it is (to increase responsiveness). Alternatively, you may wish to just poll to avoid `that.GetHints` being called too much (e.g. if someone types something in really quickly).